# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/top10_cities.csv/top10_cities.csv'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to retrieve and order cities by population and then save it to a CSV file.
I am working on google Colab
Here is the code I typed:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
DATA_DIR = 'data/'
cities = ['Tamale', 'Takoradze', 'Accra', 'Achiaman', 'Tema', 'Cape Coast', \
          'Sekondi-Takoradi', 'Obuase', 'Medina Estates', 'Koforidua', 'Japekrom', 'Kumasi']
population = [360579, 232919, 1963264, 202932, 155782, 143015, 138872, 137856, 101207, 96266, 96000, 1468609]
sample_df = pd.concat([pd.Series(cities, name='city'), 
                       pd.Series(population, name='population')], axis=1)
sample_df.sort_values(by=['city'], inplace=True)
sample_df.head(12)
def save_top10_cities(data_in, file_name='top10_cities.csv'):
    sample_df.sort_values(by='population', ascending=False).to_csv('file_path', index=False)
    sample_df['order'] = sample_df['population'].rank(ascending=False)
    data_in.sort_values('population', ascending=False).head(10)[['order', 'city', 'population']].to_csv(file_name, index=False)
    return save_top10_cities
save_top10_cities(sample_df)
print(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'top10_cities.csv'), index_col='order'))
```

my code return this following error
Please someone can help me how I can achieve my goal?

````
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-45b4074d4fe9> in <module>()
      1 save_top10_cities(sample_df)
----> 2 print(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'top10_cities.csv'), index_col='order'))

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   2008         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   2009 
-> 2010         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   2011         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   2012 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/top10_cities.csv/top10_cities.csv/top10_cities.csv'

```
````

Comment: so what's the actual file path for `top10_cities.csv`?

Comment: Your error says it all. You are saving to 'top10_cities.csv' but trying to load ''data/top10_cities.csv/top10_cities.csv/top10_cities.csv"

Comment: the actual is DATA_DIR = 'data/'

Comment: what I should do @Dimitry? I m not failiar with Python is one of my first project

Comment: I ve changed the directory from DATA_DIR = 'data/' to 'data/top10_cities.csv' but the issue still the same

Comment: `print(pd.read_csv('top10_cities.csv', index_col='order'))`

Comment: Did you mean `.to_csv(file_name` instead of `.to_csv('file_path'` inside the `save_top10_cities`? Because that code right is creating a file literally called `file_path`.